How to sync sensory data and video frame received using 'IP webcam'
I am working on a computer vision problem. I want to use video data along with sensory data from my mobile phone. Therefore I installed an app named, "IP webcam". The is able to locally host my video data and sensory data. Hence, I can get it using the 'get' requests. The sensory data comes with a timestamp in the 'from' block like:
http://192.168.36.62:8080/sensors.json?from=1716438984043&sense=accel,battery_charging,mag,gyro,light,proximity,gravity,lin_accel,rot_vector,battery_voltage,battery_level,battery_temp
but the video data comes continuously at "http://192.168.36.62:8080/video".
I am unable to find any way to get the timestamp data, except thinking to use another app or build an app myself for this purpose (but it might be waste of time to build an app for an perhaps already solved purpose.)

So something like: https://github.com/MobileRoboticsSkoltech/OpenCamera-Sensors , F-Droid link Based on Issues I am unclear about support but it is open-source so if acceptable can be modified.
